# Automated testing tools for iOS apps

Tags: automated-testing, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some tools for testing Mobile web apps?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-some-tools-for-testing-mobile-web-apps)

I wanted to know if there are any good automated testing tools that can be used to test iOS apps. Looking for some pointers.

Comment: Have you tried a Google search for "ios test automation tools"?

Comment: There was also some very good answers in the following question: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-some-tools-for-testing-mobile-web-apps

Comment: Hi @sahi16, welcome to SQA! Questions that are very broad rarely get useful answers here. If you could provide a bit more context, it's likely that people will be more able to help you - if you're not sure how to do that, read this for some more ideas: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't agree that this is a dupe of "what are some tools for testing mobile web apps". That question is specifically about mobile *web* apps, this question is about testing iOS apps, which aren't necessarily *web* apps. You will use different tools to test native apps vs web apps.

Comment: @pete-hodgson Could you suggest some edits to the question that would make that distinction clearer? I'd like to hear why you'd want to use different tools, and what the differences would be. As it stands at the moment, I'd agree with user246's assessment - it's a question better asked of Google rather than SQA. Maybe you could help to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Frank](http://www.testingwithfrank.com). It's a tool for writing automated acceptance tests for native iOS applications. Sort of like Selenium for native apps. There are screencasts and presentations on the Frank website that give a good introduction to the tool. Most people today drive it using Cucumber, but recently (Oct 2011) a Java driver called Victor was released.

Full Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the Frank project :)

Comment: I like Frank, too. I wrote Victor, the Java front end: https://github.com/dhemery/victor

Answer (score 1):

Try Fone monkey.
Or
www.perfectomobile.com

Answer (score 0):

sahi16!

For example, I can reccomend the following one: [Froglogic Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/products/editions.php)

We use it for testing our Qt Win application and it looks great! Will try it for iOS.