# any suggestions on automation tools for mobile application?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some tools for testing Mobile web apps?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-some-tools-for-testing-mobile-web-apps)

Me and my friends have developed an application for all the mobile platforms.

The mobile camera opens immediately after the launching of app, & should capture the image for further proceedings.

Can anyone please suggest me any automation tool to test this app.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, niranjan.  Can you tell us where you have already looked?  For example, did you try http://lmgtfy.com/?q=mobile+application+testing+tools?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the part of the camera, but for mobile testing we have used [SeeTest](http://experitest.com) with pretty good results.

Answer (score 0):

I watched the instructional videos for DeviceAnywhere and it looked promising for this sort of testing, however I never used it myself: http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/FullRender/Test_Automation_Training.html

Answer (score 0):

[AppThwack](https://www.appthwack.com) tests mobile apps (Android native, hybrid, and web) on real phones and tablets hosted in a lab. I co-created it, so I'm admittedly biased.

For web you enter a URL and the site is rendered on a pool of ~20 devices in multiple browsers (Native, Chrome, Dolphin HD, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile, Firefox). We display screen-shots for each one and the entire cycle takes about 4.5 minutes.

For Android native and hybrid apps, we install, launch, take screen-shots in portrait and landscape, randomly hit it with UI input, and then run any custom JUnit (Robotium, etc) tests you've uploaded. This happens on ~60 devices and takes about 3.5 minutes. The report is generated in real time and contains full logcat dumps and other detailed information.

For creating your own custom automated content you should check out Robotium for Android, Selenium for web, or a cross-platform tool like [MonkeyTalk](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk).

Answer (score 0):

Be thorough with your research on automation.  I have not used AppThwack, but have had extensive exposure to Device Anywhere, and I found it sub-optimal.  Latency, lag, and device down-time were large factors.  My old shop had all North American handsets on-site, so we would use Device Anywhere for Canadian devices/providers.  patience must be a virtue with services like these.

Also, I did not automate any testing on Device Anywhere, I did everything manually and encountered hiccups/lag/et al, so if there is some automation script that you will be running, be wary that it can handle unexpected wait times.

Answer (score 0):

Intuit has their iOS automation framework available through open source, its called [IMAT](https://code.intuit.com/sf/sfmain/do/viewProject/projects.ginsu). I work there, this what we use for our iOS apps.

Answer (score -4):

you can use the selenium webdriver

Comment: Welcome to SQA Stack Exchange, shwetha! Could you provide some more details about how Selenium Webdriver will help test a mobile app? It doesn't seem intuitive to me.