# Which automation tool should be learn for mobile devices?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile

I am working as a manual tester.I need to learn automation because my company has mobile application projects in pipeline process.

So please suggest which tool should I learn ? Thanks in advance

Comment: First tool you need to learn is Google search. This question is asked every week in this forum and has many answers. Some people who gave quality answers before may not like writing them again, or even linking them for you. If **YOU** cannot be bothered to make your own research, why anyone else should?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some tools for testing Mobile web apps?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-some-tools-for-testing-mobile-web-apps)

Answer (score 3):

This question is very broad and is one of those question which is bound to get biased replies based on User's opinions.

So when you say,

> So please suggest which tool should I learn

There is no definitive, clear-cut answer, until we understand the projects that are in pipeline are.

Nevertheless, on the top of my head, I can name quite a few mobile automation tools here :

- [Appium](http://appium.io/)
- [Calaba.sh](http://calaba.sh/)
- [Robotium](https://github.com/robotiumtech/robotium)
- [Monkeytalk](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk)
- [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/)

Here is a link of such tools, which I compiled in my blog few months ago :

https://qatechnicals.wordpress.com/testing-tools/best-mobile-automation-tools/

Answer (score 1):

> I am working as a manual tester.

If I understand correctly the term "manual tester" then the first and most important  thing to learn is programming- a language but also concepts and principles, the language and environment are not that important.

Comment: I agree with your answer.i learned selenium tool but it won't support for mobile devices.so am more intense to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to functional testing tools in case of your mobile application performs network communication with the backend server you might want to check the performance in case of several hundreds or thousands simultaneous mobile applications operations.

In that case consider using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) in combination with the [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) to record the activity of a single application and replay it with increased number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the tools told by *log_file*, you can also take a look on [SeeTest](https://experitest.com/automation/)
and [Silk Mobile](http://www.borland.com/Products/Software-Testing/Automated-Testing/Silk-Mobile), which are very similar and both intended for native app automation on iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Windows Mobile, BlackBerry and Symbian.

Anyway, these tools record steps and present them in a visual script interface, letting you export them to many programming languages. Therefore, maybe the first thing you should learn is JUnit, which will give you the ability to modify those scripts and make them more robust and powerful.