# Android Quality Assurance Tool for Android

Tags: automated-testing, android

As a part of my class project I need to implement UI testing and QA testing on my sample android app which I have developed in Eclipse a while ago.

I am thinking to run the Robotium as part of UI automation test.
And I am implementing the JUnit for unit test cases.

I am stuck up with tools for QA testing. Can some one suggest me the tools for QA testing in Android.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer my answer here http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/14670/7313

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of tools available in market for your QA testing part of Android apps. A couple of them you can find below:-

1. [Appium](http://appium.io/) (already suggested by wmarchewka)
2. [Robotium](http://robotium.com/) (Paid tool)
3. [EggPlant](http://www.testplant.com/eggplant/testing-tools/eggplant-mobile-eggon/) (paid tool)
4. [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) (Free tool)
5. [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) (Free)

you can find more information over these and other tools at this [link](http://www.optimusinfo.com/blog/top-10-mobile-testing-tools/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I will go ahead with Robotium...

Answer (score 0):

Try [Appium](http://appium.io/) it is one of best test automation framework for mobile devices. 
If You are familiar with Selenium WebDriver You should like it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answers given by Dhiman and wmarchewka, here is another list of mobile testing tools for Android :

- [MonkeyTalk](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk)
- [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/)
- [Calaba.sh](http://calaba.sh/)
- [SeeTest](https://experitest.com/automation/)
- [Silk Mobile](http://www.borland.com/en-GB/Products/Software-Testing/Automated-Testing/Silk-Mobile)
- [CatJS](http://catjsteam.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

- Appium (iOS/Android)
- Robotium
- Selendroid
- MonkeyRunner
- Calabash
- Sikuli
- SeeTest

you can find more information on these and other Android & iOS Mobile Testing [Tools Here](http://www.guru99.com/mobile-testing-tools.html).

Comment: How is this different to the tools already suggested above?